# How do I extract a file name from the filepath column using ADF expression builder?

Tags: azure-data-factory, expressionbuilder

I would like to get filename from below path using Visual expression builder in dataflow derived column in data factory.

```
/datafactory/raw/files/filename.csv
```

every row has got filepath. So filename is required in every row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the count of `/` is fixed in your filepath, such as `/datafactory/raw/files/filename.csv`, you can use this expression in Derived Column:`split(filepath,'/')[5]`.Otherwise, you can try this expression:`split(filepath,'/')[size(split(filepath,'/'))]`.

Data preview of Derived Column:

[image]

Comment: Steve - will split(filepath,'/')[-1] work too?

Comment: @azuresnowflake1 No, it doesn't work. It will give `NULL` result.

Comment: split(filepath,'/')[size(split(filepath,'/'))] - worked for me. thank you.